# tensor flow CPU usage drops after saving

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a tensorflow computation graph. The same graph was running fine before but all of a sudden I noticed that after saving the graph using 
saver the CPU usage drops from more than 600% to 100% for the rest of the session. It seems like all executors are dying when saving and the computation keeps running on only 1 Core.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, SAVE_MODEL)
```

This started happening lately, On the same graph this didn't happen before.
any idea for this random behavior ?

thanks

[image]

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug. Can you post a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) with instructions for reproducing the problem?

Comment: I am suspecting a certain type of timeout of some sort.  Maybe saving is taking too long and workers and timing out ?

Comment: (We should continue this discussion on an issue thread...) In the screenshot of the CPU load, has the saving completed yet?

Comment: Saving completed and after it is complete CPU usage drops. I just noticed that I haven't upgraded tensor flow and i am still using version 1.1.0. I will upgrade and re-run again.  If I encounter the same issue again then I will create an issue unless you want me to create an issue thread regardless.